# A class extending another class, How to Make it as an Exception class,?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

If my class already extends some other class, what should I do if I want an instance of my class to be  thrown as an Exception object?

The only method I found is that some superclass must be extending Exception class. Is there any other way?
EDIT: Also does this indicate a design flaw, if yes then please explain how
What is the right way to use a custom exception in your class, Is it by adding a reference of the custom Exception in your class OR calling 'new' whenever you require it, Can you give a code outline?

Comment: If your class is an exception and something else, you should probably split it....

Comment: It would be creating a new object  on the fly whenever you want to throw your custom exception...

Answer (score 3):

You will have to wrap it in another class. In java you can only throw subtypes of Throwable, which is a class.

Example:

```
public class Wrapper extends Exception {
    public final MyClass wrapped;
    public Wrapper(MyClass toWrap) { wrapped = toWrap; }
}
```

If this is an application of the [trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29) technique, or similiar control flow techniques, then there are ways to *not* get a stack trace (reducing the time it takes to create the object). I can look it up if need be.

Answer (score 2):

A Way out could be Define your class with generics to take Exception as parameter. This way you will be able to make other feel that in some sense this is exception.

```
public class One{}

public class Two<E extends Exception> extends One {
    E e = null;
    public void throwE() throws E {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

PS Note: I have already assumed that you know that it is not possible since you will have to extends Exception class for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the class you are extending than you should have that class extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.

Otherwise, there is no way you can do this.

Comment: You can extend other classes that are child of `Exception` in order to define a new `Exception`.

Comment: Was I telling anything that suggests you can't?

Comment: *that class [must] extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException`. Otherwise, there is no way you can do this* yes, it looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

Java allows single inheritance, so you can extend only `Exception`/`Throwable` or other class. There is no other way to allow class to behave like exception. Of course you can still implement as many interfaces as you want.

That being said, it's very strange you want to throw something that already subclasses other class. Are you trying to transport some data through layers by throwing an exception and catching it later? Controlling the program flow using exceptions is a big anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's it, you can only throw `Throwable` classes. `Throwable` is a concrete class, not an interface, so you have to modify your object hierarchy to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you must extend `java.lang.Throwable` to be able to throw and instance. You can extend it directly or from any of its non-final subclasses, typically `java.lang.RuntimeException` or `java.lang.Exception`.

You need to re-think you design around this constrain.